# Constant solution and uniqueness of separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning ODE and I have some problems that confuse me.
In the textbook I am reading, it explains that if we have a separable ODE: $$x'=h(t)g(x(t))$$
then $x=k$ is the only constant solution iff $x$ is a zero of $g$.
Moreover, it says "all other non-constant solutions are separated by the straight line $x=k$ ".

First, why do we do this separation between finding constant and non-constant solutions?

Second, I don't understand the quoted sentence. why is that?

Third, there is an example of finding a solution to the initial value problem $$x'=2tx^3$$ and $x(0)=1$. They say that the only constant solution is $x \equiv 0$, and
"Therefore if $x(t)$ is a solution such that $x(0)=1$, then, by uniqueness, $x(t)$ cannot assume the value 0 anywhere. Since $x(0) =1 >0$, we infer that the solution is always positive."

But how can $x \equiv 0$ be a constant solution if the solution should satisfy $x(0)=1$, and how they got that the solution should be positive?

I am really confused and need some help with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(k)=0$, then $x(t)=k$ satisfies the differential equation. On the other hand, if $x(t)=k$ his a constant solution then
$$
0=x'(t)=h(t)g(x(t))=h(t)g(k)\quad\forall t\implies g(k)=0.
$$
Suppose now that $k$ is the only zero of $g$ and that conditions for uniqueness of solution hold ($g$ is locally Lipschitz). Then the graph of two different solutions cannot cross, since otherwise there would be two different solutions passing through the crossing point.

If $x(0)=k$, the unique solution is the constant solution $x(t)=k$. If $x(0)>k$, then the unique solution must stay above the line $x=k$, since it cannot cross it. Similarly if $x(0)<k$.